# How to get data from Aerys parseBody if the data doesn't have key

Tags: php, amphp

I am working with [Aerys](https://github.com/amphp/aerys) but I have a problem. When I send my parameters through `post` I don't know how to access to the data.

In the documentation they use the following function:

`$body = yield parseBody($request);`

In the [documentation](https://github.com/amphp/aerys/blob/master/docs/http.md#request-bodies), there are two functions to use the `parseBody`  they use `get` or `getArray` with the key to get the data. As I said before I am sending an array of data but this array does not have a specific `key` to be accessed.

do you have any idea how to get the data of that array? If print `$body` it returns an object.

`Aerys\ParsedBody Object
(
    [fields:Aerys\ParsedBody:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => %222f384ae8-004b-44e1-8c6b-9b2a249b069f%22
                )
         )
)`

Comment: can you try this and let me know `$values = array_values( $array);
echo $values[0];` what does this echo you?

Comment: How does your actual request body look like, i.e. `var_dump(yield $request->getBody());`?

Comment: @D.'s that is not going to work because `$body = yield parseBody($request)` return and Object.

@kelunik the request is the Object that I referred in my comment above.  `Aerys\ParsedBody Object`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way, but it works for me. I found this post about [Access Private and Protected Properties of Objects in PHP](https://blag.kazeno.net/development/access-private-protected-properties) I hope that it works for you.

```
$body = yield parseBody($request);
$boddy = (Array) $body;
$boddy = array_values($boddy);
```

I get the request from `parseBody` after that I make that an `array`, the problem that I have in this step is that I have as a key a `class` that is complex to access so I return the value from that `array`.